# React Native fetch method makes multiple API calls on the server

Tags: react-native

I am using fetch method to make API calls on the server and noted it is making multiple requests at the same time and due to this it increases 30% RPM on the server

Can someone please help in preventing multiple calls and understanding why is it happening?

Below you can see React Native code and server logs

**React Native Code**

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Accept': "application/json",
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
        }
    }).then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status === 200) {
        resp.text().then(function(data) {
        var resData = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Logs**

```
[Wed Jan 25 12:14:08.323939 2017] [:error] [pid 13832] 2017-01-25 12:14:08.323658 URL:  /driver/upcoming-bookings/ User:  {'id': '', 'email': 'Anonymous'} HTTP Method: GET Params:  {u'imei': u'359375062977098'} 
[Wed Jan 25 12:14:08.631057 2017] [:error] [pid 14306] 2017-01-25 12:14:08.630777 URL:  /driver/upcoming-bookings/ User:  {'id': '', 'email': 'Anonymous'} HTTP Method: GET Params:  {u'imei': u'359375062977098'}  
[Wed Jan 25 12:14:09.103341 2017] [:error] [pid 14307] 2017-01-25 12:14:09.102915 URL:  /driver/upcoming-bookings/ User:  {'id': '', 'email': 'Anonymous'} HTTP Method: GET Params:  {u'imei': u'359375062977098'}
```

Comment: Where are you exactly calling this code? Please tell me is not from a render function.

Comment: In `componentWillMount` and in few screens on swipe of a button

Comment: Just did a snif with Wireshark and everything works fine. One HTTP request per fetch call. So I'm guessing you're messing somehow before calling this function.

Comment: @Eldelshell: What exactly I need to change in my code to make it work fine?

Comment: I would remove any call to this service from any component that does multiple state changes or animations. Also, try placing your code on `componentDidMount`.

Comment: What about the cases when I am calling the API on click of a button? in this case, no component involved but still getting multiple requests on the server